# validate order attribute in xsd for xml file

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have a problem in xsd, i dont know why stackoverflow is preventing me from asking.
I want to have a tag that looks like this

```
      <tag order="1">
      <something>something</something>
      </tag>
```

but i also want to validate this using validation.

in xsd, i have

```
<xsd:element name="tag">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="something">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:complexType>
```

i can individually pass syntax test but when i put both validation and the xml file together, i kept getting errors that say order attribute is not allowed to appear in this tag. 
I want to use this order attribute because it is required. If anyone can kindly let me know how! Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the attribute declaration to the complex type:

```
<xsd:element name="tag">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="something">
   <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute name="order" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```